# What is the method of joining fabric to the glove and helmet rings in a spacesuit called?

Tags: spacesuits

What would you call the method of joining fabric to the glove and helmet rings in a spacesuit by clamping it between two metal rings?

Comment: I don't know what methods are used, but I think sewing the fabric to the rings should be possible. Another method  would be to clamp the fabric between two concentric rings. Heat sealing by HF energy between the fabric and a plastic ring might be possible too. Gluing the fabric between two concentric rings may be another method. A combination of some ot these methods is possible.